# elasticsearch doesn't raise score when matching on n-gram inside should clause

Tags: python, elasticsearch

i'm trying to search an item inside elastic search, and raise the score in case i find an sku or something like that.

this is my index configuration:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
          "ngram_analyzer": {
              "tokenizer": "ngram_tokenizer"
          }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
          "ngram_tokenizer": {
              "type": "ngram",
              "min_gram": 2,
              "max_gram": 3,
              "token_chars": [
                  "letter",
                  "digit",
                  "symbol",
                  "whitespace",
                  "punctuation"
              ]
          }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "job_desc": {
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer"
    },
      "sku": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
              "keyword": {"type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256}
          }
      },
      "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
              "keyword": {"type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256}
          }
      },
      "unit_price": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
              "keyword": {"type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256}
          }
      },
      "unit_type": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
              "keyword": {"type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256}
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my query to find the item:

```
{
    "bool": {
        "must": {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "<name of item & possibly sku>",
                "fields": [
                    "name",
                    "sku"
                ]
            }
        },
        "should": {
            "match": {
                "job_desc": {
                    "query": "424241 (sku of item)",
                    "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but for some reason, the "should" clause does not raise the score of the search.
what is the issue here?

thanks in advance,
Yaniv Akiva

Comment: can you please share some sample documents, over which you are hitting your search query?

Comment: sure,

{
    "_index": "my_index",
    "_id": "c6f057b865",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
        "name": "002 - name of item",
        "sku": "002",
        "unit_price": 5,
        "unit_type": "kg"
    }
}
{
    "_index": "my_index",
    "_id": "4c68cea7e5",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
        "name": "001 - name of item",
        "sku": "001",
        "unit_price": "0",
        "unit_type": "kg"
    }
}


@ESCoder

Comment: @ESCoder can you assist?